# My dollar calculator isn't working exactly as I want it to in java?

Tags: java, jgrasp

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Part2 {

    public static void main(String []args) {

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
         DecimalFormat decimalformat = new DecimalFormat("##0; ##0");
         double a, b, answer;
         double nOnebills, nFivebills, nTenbills;
         double nTwentybills, nFiftybills, nOnehundredbills;
         double int nPenny, nNickle, nDime, nQuarter;

         System.out.println("Please input the amount the customer owns.");
         a = input.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Please input the amount the customer paid.");
         b = input.nextDouble();

         answer = a - b;
         System.out.println("The amount of change given back to the customer "+ 
         money.format(answer));
         nOnehundredbills = (answer)/(100);

         if (nOnehundredbills <= 0) {
             System.out.println("The number of hundred dollar bills in your change is 0"); 
         } else {
             System.out.println("The number of hundred dollar bills in your change is "+ nOnehundredbills);
         }
    }
}
```

The output was this:

```
Please input the amount the customer owns.
100
Please input the amount the customer paid.
200
The amount of change given back to the customer ($100.00)
The number of hundred dollar bills in your change is 0
```

The 0 should be a 1 since 100 divided by 100 is 1 and 1 is not less than or equal to zero so it should have gone to the else statement.

Comment: You should double check this condition `if (nOnehundredbills <= 0)
   System.out.println("The number of hundred dollar bills in your change is 
    0"); 
  else
   System.out.println("The number of hundred dollar bills in your change is 
 "+nOnehundredbills);`

**in your code answer = -100**

Comment: why two types are declared double and int here"double int nPenny,nNickle,nDime,nQuarter"?  does your code compile even?

Comment: The customer pays more than he owns...

Comment: its a section of the code,i see my mistake

Comment: I think some of the confusion is that negative $100 is displayed as ($100)

Comment: int was a typo raju hoho

Comment: what does the condition "if (nOnehundredbills <= 0)" means if nOnehundredbills is negative (-1)

Comment: the money format made the -100 to $100 oh boy i see the mistake

Answer (score 1):

you should write

```
 answer =b-a;//not a-b
```

Since you wrote `a-b`, the answer will have a value of `-1`,
which will definitely enter the first if statement because `-1<=0`.